# form validation starts from the lower field.why such strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS and here the form validation starts from "name" field after that phone field then it goes email and then again upper field and so on.Why such strange behaviour of starting the validation from bottom field even though validation is correct?

```js
function checkform(pform1) {
  var uname = pform1.username.value;
  var pswrd = pform1.password.value;
  var repswrd = pform1.repassword.value;
  var email = pform1.email.value;
  var phone = pform1.phone.value;
  var name = pform1.name.value;
  var cleanstr = phone.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');
  var err = {};
  var validemail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
  var minNumberofChars = 6;
  var maxNumberofChars = 16;
  var regularExpression = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;

  //check required fields
  //password should be minimum 6 chars but not greater than 16
  if (uname == null || uname == "") {
    err.message = "UserName can't be blank";
    err.field = pform1.username;
  }
  if ((pswrd.length < minNumberofChars) || (pswrd.length > maxNumberofChars)) {
    err.message = "Invalid password length";
    err.field = pform1.password;
  } else if (!regularExpression.test(pswrd)) {
    err.message = "password should contain atleast one number and one special character";
    err.field = pform1.password;
  }

  //validate email
  if (!(validemail.test(email))) {
    err.message = "Invalid email";
    err.field = pform1.email;
  }

  //check phone number
  if (isNaN(parseInt(cleanstr))) {
    err.message = "Invalid phone number";
    err.field = pform1.phone;
  } else if (phone.length < 10 || phone.length > 10) {
    err.message = "please enter valid phone number";
    err.field = pform1.phone;
  }
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    err.message = "Name can't be blank";
    err.field = pform1.name;
  }
  if (pswrd !== repswrd) {
    err.message = "Password wont match";
    err.field = pform1.repassword;
  }
  if (err.message) {
    document.getElementById('divError').innerHTML = err.message;
    err.field.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    window.location.href = "newform2.html";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title> Form Handling </title>
  <!-- <link href="formstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <h3> Welcome!Please fillup all the details
  </h3>

  <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">

    <div id="errmsgbox">

      <div id="divError" style="color:#FF0000">
      </div>

    </div>

    <fieldset class="credentials">
      <legend> Access Credentials
      </legend>

      <table border="0">

        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="username" class="hover"> Username
              </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="required text" autofocus />
            <span class="style1"> *
                    </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="password" class="hover"> Password
                              </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="required text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                    </span><br />
            <span class="tooltip"> Minimum 6 and maximum 16 characters
                                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="repassword" class="hover"> Re - enter Password
                                                  </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" id="repassword" class="required text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                        </span><br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="email" class="hover"> Email
                                                                    </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="required email text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                                          </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Other Information
      </legend>
      <table border="0">

        <tr>
          <td width="59">
            <label for="name" class="hover"> Name
                                                                                                </label>
          </td>
          <td width="207">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="required text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                                                                      </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="phone" class="hover"> Phone
                                                                                                                </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="phone" class="phone text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                                                                                      </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="submit" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"> * = Required Field
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

the form validation starts from "name" field

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Javascript executes in order, so it validates in the order that you program it in the `checkform()` function.

Comment: Are you talking about where the focus goes when there are multiple errors? The focus goes to `err.field`, and each validation check overwrites this. So focus will go to the last field that was assigned there.

Comment: And `err.message` is the message from the last field that failed validation.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you Mr Barmar,You made my day.its working fine now. I will keep asking queries..itz first tym working as front end developer than a backend..Keep suggesting.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each validation failure overwrites `err.message` and `err.field`. So at the end, these contain the last field that failed validation.

The simple way to fix this is to change all your `if` statements to `else if`. That way, if one of the earlier checks fails, you won't perform any of the rest, and `err.message` and `err.field` will contain the first failure instead of the last.

```js
function checkform(pform1) {
  var uname = pform1.username.value;
  var pswrd = pform1.password.value;
  var repswrd = pform1.repassword.value;
  var email = pform1.email.value;
  var phone = pform1.phone.value;
  var name = pform1.name.value;
  var cleanstr = phone.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');
  var err = {};
  var validemail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
  var minNumberofChars = 6;
  var maxNumberofChars = 16;
  var regularExpression = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;

  //check required fields
  //password should be minimum 6 chars but not greater than 16
  if (uname == null || uname == "") {
    err.message = "UserName can't be blank";
    err.field = pform1.username;
  }
  else if ((pswrd.length < minNumberofChars) || (pswrd.length > maxNumberofChars)) {
    err.message = "Invalid password length";
    err.field = pform1.password;
  } else if (!regularExpression.test(pswrd)) {
    err.message = "password should contain atleast one number and one special character";
    err.field = pform1.password;
  }

  //validate email
  else if (!(validemail.test(email))) {
    err.message = "Invalid email";
    err.field = pform1.email;
  }

  //check phone number
  else if (isNaN(parseInt(cleanstr))) {
    err.message = "Invalid phone number";
    err.field = pform1.phone;
  } else if (phone.length < 10 || phone.length > 10) {
    err.message = "please enter valid phone number";
    err.field = pform1.phone;
  }
  else if (name == null || name == "") {
    err.message = "Name can't be blank";
    err.field = pform1.name;
  }
  else if (pswrd !== repswrd) {
    err.message = "Password wont match";
    err.field = pform1.repassword;
  }

  if (err.message) {
    document.getElementById('divError').innerHTML = err.message;
    err.field.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    window.location.href = "newform2.html";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title> Form Handling </title>
  <!-- <link href="formstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <h3> Welcome!Please fillup all the details
  </h3>

  <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">

    <div id="errmsgbox">

      <div id="divError" style="color:#FF0000">
      </div>

    </div>

    <fieldset class="credentials">
      <legend> Access Credentials
      </legend>

      <table border="0">

        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="username" class="hover"> Username
              </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="required text" autofocus />
            <span class="style1"> *
                    </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="password" class="hover"> Password
                              </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="required text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                    </span><br />
            <span class="tooltip"> Minimum 6 and maximum 16 characters
                                        </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="repassword" class="hover"> Re - enter Password
                                                  </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" id="repassword" class="required text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                        </span><br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="email" class="hover"> Email
                                                                    </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="required email text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                                          </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Other Information
      </legend>
      <table border="0">

        <tr>
          <td width="59">
            <label for="name" class="hover"> Name
                                                                                                </label>
          </td>
          <td width="207">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="required text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                                                                      </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="phone" class="hover"> Phone
                                                                                                                </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="phone" class="phone text" />
            <span class="style1"> *
                                                                                                                      </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="submit" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"> * = Required Field
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```